# What is geom_way column in osm2po generated data?

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2po

Could anybody tell me the meaning of geom_way column generated by osm2po?

Answer (score 1):

It is the geometry in [WKB format](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.3/ch04.html#id2570912). It's often named `the_geom`. You can modify the pgRouting writer plugin when you prefer another name: https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting-contrib/blob/master/plugin-osm2po/PgRoutingWriter.java

Comment: Does this data needed for short path search?

Comment: Not needed if you use the Dijkstra Algorithm, though x/y values of start and end node might be pre-calculated already. But you usually want to use the line geometry to draw the route later.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:
Open the generated SQL-File in an editor and modify the name in line 10.